# PowerShell - Respond to a Command response

Tags: powershell, command-line, scripting, automation

I am trying to write a simple script that will execute a console command in Windows, which will always ask for a confirmation for overwriting the existing data.  I thought something like the below would work, but it appears I was mistaken (and no surprise, write-host doesn't interact with the command line, I believe it simply puts text on screen).  Can anyone provide some advice on how to handle this?  I need to be able to execute the script through task scheduler on a weekly basis with no interaction.

Script:

```
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath pw -ArgumentList @"
    threshold checkpoint create "WeeklyBackup" "WeeklyBackup"
"@
sleep -Seconds 3
$confirm = Select-String -pattern "About to over-write existing CheckPoint 'WeeklyBackup'." -Quiet

if ($confirm)
{
   Write-Host "Y`r" 
}
```

What I expect to see in the console:

```
D:\BMC_Software\ProactiveNet>pw threshold checkpoint create "WeeklyBackup" "Week
lyBackup"
About to over-write existing CheckPoint 'WeeklyBackup'. Do you want to proceed?
(y/n)
```

Then a user would hit Y and carriage-return and the process would be done.  But I want this automated.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Have you tried just doing `echo "Y\`r" | pw`?

Comment: Well, that simplified things a lot, works just as it needs to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo "Y`r" | pw
```

This is typically used from batch files but it usually works just as well from PowerShell.

Comment: Appreciate it, I'll probably put it in a batch file instead now, since I don't really need to use any logical comparisons.

Comment: The only problem with the batch file is that you might have trouble sending the carriage return. If you don't actually need the CR then by all means. You can also send multiple characters that way, so in batch you could do `echo yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy | pw` and have it answer what might be lots of prompts.

Comment: One possible way to send CR in a batch would be to create a text file that contains as many "Y"s as you need, all on separate lines, then do this: `type y.txt | pw`